# Why can't I use a template integer when initializing a std::vector?

Tags: c++, class, templates, vector, initialization

I'm trying to create a class BigInt that contains a std::vector with D elements.

```
template<int D>
class BigInt
{
    public:
        std::vector<short> digit(D, 0);
};
```

I'm getting an error stating that **'D' is not a type**

Comment: At class scope, you can only use `= ...` and `{...}` initializers, not `(...)`. Also, consider using `std::array` instead of `std::vector` if you don't need `digit` to be resizable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is [default member initializer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization) (since C++11) only supports equal-sign (or braced) initializer, but not
parentheses initializer.

You can

```
template<int D>
class BigInt
{
    public:
        std::vector<short> digit = std::vector<short>(D, 0);
};
```

You can also use [member initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization) in constructor instead of *default member initializer*.

```
template<int D>
class BigInt
{
    public:
        std::vector<short> digit;

        BigInt() : digit(D, 0) {}
};
```

BTW: `std::vector<short>(D, 0)` has the same effect as `std::vector<short>(D)`; you can use the latter for convenience.